# PHP POST to URL with user being redirected

Tags: php, post, paypal

So I'm making a check out cart on my website. I'm using PayPal as the payment system but before I transfer the customers to PayPal I get their details. To do that I POST from index.php to index.php, run my code to retrieve the POSTed info and store it in a database and now wish to redirect the customer to PayPal.

Unfortunately you have to POST all the cart data to PayPal:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

The only way I see around this is to post to index.php, collect the user data, then have a button show up saying click here to pay via PayPal. That's one extra step that I want to avoid.

Any way to POST to index.php, collect the data, then post the PayPal info to the PayPal website? Or any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would need 2 forms on your page, one form that posts back to index.php and a second form that posts to paypal

after the first form posts back to index.php, echo javascript in the body tag to submit the paypal form when it loads

```
    <?php
   if(isset($_POST['mydatafield'])){

        do database stuff

        $LOAD = 'document.paypal.submit();';
    }
    ?>
    <body onload="<?php echo $LOAD ?>">
    <form name="paypal" action="paypal.com?yadayada">
    paypal fields
    </form>
    <form name="myform" action="index.php">
    your form stuff
    submit button
    </form>
```

Comment: That does look like it'd work. Is this a normal way of doing something like this? It's a bit strange that this has to be done right?

Comment: Eh im sure there are other ways, its the way I do it on my website. You need to redirect the user to paypal to pay, but you also need to save the order in your system. Having the form submitted on the body load is like automatically pressing a paypal submit button (which you dont want the user to have to do), the user will just be directed to paypal after they press your checkout button.

Comment: EDIT *techinically on my site when you click submit, it posts back to the same page, but instead of showing the checkout fields again (which you might see depending on how long paypal's posts take) I hide them and show a "connecting to paypal" splash screen so the user knows something is working in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You may fire submitting programmatically with JavaScript, eg:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paypal_form">
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitPay(){
  document.getElementById("paypal_form").submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You do **not** need to **re**-post your form from the client in the sense mentioned in other answers. You can instead use **cURL** to **POST** the data to PayPal and make it all look transparent to the user. Kinda like a forwarding of the posted form. You act on the data (save it, manipulate it or whatever) and forward the post to Paypal all in a single user transaction.

Here's a simple example: http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Comment: Incorrect; since the client must be redirected to PayPal along with the POST data.
A GET query string and header() is your only option (without delving into JavaScript hacks). In a different scenario where a client doesn't need to be redirected to PayPal what you suggest would work fine.

Comment: You could actually still use the cURL approach and post the data that way. If you look at Paypal's developer samples in the **Paypal Developer Sandbox** you will see that there are numerous ways of using cURL to handle Paypal interaction. So all the data could be collected and then posted to Paypal and processed.

Comment: What else can I say besides; 'No, that's not correct'? Try it out yourself. It won't work.